# MySQL placeholders throw error on WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am using MySQL placeholders and create promise to use them with async await.

```
selectTickets: (variable) => {
    const sqlStatement = `SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE userID = ?`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sqlStatement, variable, (error, response) => {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            return resolve(response);
        });
    });
},
```

i tried even to create the statement with interpolation and gave me an error:
"Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'"

This is my code. But when I am using it in react, I am getting Error 500 status saying that the statement is incorrect.

```
ode: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE userID = ?'
```

I tried alot of other methods. But other functions that uses same type of function with same type of statement are working just fine.

In react I have this call:

```
 const URL_TICKETS_BY_USERID = 'http://localhost:3000/api/get-tickets';
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` }
};
  const userID = user.userID;

  axios.get(URL_TICKETS_BY_USERID,
        userID,
        config
    )
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Can i have some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with your `db.query()` call. The second parameter should be an array, even for single values. This should work:

```
db.query(sqlStatement, [variable], (error, response) => {
  if (error) return reject(error);
  return resolve(response);
});
```

Also axios `get()` takes two parameters: url and config (optional). This means that any params should be part of that config object:

```
const config = {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` },
  params: {
    id: user.userID
  }
};
axios.get(URL_TICKETS_BY_USERID, config)
```

Alternatively pass it as a GET parameter in the URL:

```
axios.get(URL_TICKETS_BY_USERID + "?id=" + user.userID, config)
```

Comment: I modified it. But on postman works. However, on the frontend react gives me an empty array...
I dont know if i made the axios req properly

Comment: @danielsas I amended my answer :)

Comment: thank you very very much. it worked as a parameter. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the question mark. In some database systems, the question mark is used as a placeholder for values that are passed in separately. However, it seems that in my case, the database system is not recognizing the question mark as a placeholder, and is interpreting it as part of the query.
So changed the query to:-

```
const q = `SELECT * FROM list WHERE userid = ${listId}`;
```

I passed the variable inside the query and it works now